« Droit manuaire »: sens
Question : sens de « droit manuaire » (APHORISMES SUR LA SAGESSE DANS LA VIE, Arthur Schopenhauer, première traduction par J. A. Cantacuzène)

La maxime qu'il vaut mieux inspirer la crainte que la confiance ne serait pas si fausse, vu le peu de fond que l'on peut faire de la justice des hommes, si nous vivions dans l'état de nature où chacun doit par soi-même garder sa personne et défendre ses droits. Mais elle ne trouve plus d'application dans notre époque de civilisation, où l'État a pris sur lui la protection de la personne et de la propriété; elle n'est plus là que comme ces châteaux et ces donjons de l'époque du droit manuaire, inutiles et abandonnés, au milieu de campagnes bien cultivées, de chaussées animées, voire même de voies ferrées.

Le TLFi est muet sur ce mot, et ce que je peux trouver d'autre sources concerne la typographie, ce qui ne peut pas avoir de rapport avec le sens de l'expression « droit manuaire ».
Wikipédia, manuaire
Larousse, manuaire
Il semble donc que « manuaire » ait un autre sens dans cette expression, comme s'il signifiait « force », mais ce n'est que spéculation de ma part.
On peut déterminer que c'est un concept assez répugnant en lisant l'extrait suivant.

De l'influence de la réformation de Luther sur la croyance ... ROBELOT (Chanoine de Dijon.) · 1822

Having lost their 'precious' droit seigneur/de cuissage , maybe the frustrated lords resorted to taking matters into their own hands. = droit manuaire ?

@PapaPoule I don't think this state of affairs has anything to do with the loss of the "droit de cuissage", which in fact they kept enjoying the whole time that lasted the unruliness and horror of feodalism (and after). Rather I believe it is a consequence of the opportunism to which the powerful is prone to succumb if the times are right (no overseeing authority, for instance). Reading above the text in the reference in my answer tends to show that (« une authorité éloignée qui prétend tirer son pouvoir du ciel »); in other words they thought they could lie with impunity and abuse the weak.

On trouve une définition sommaire dans un ouvrage datant de 1836, Dictionnaire comparatif et étymologique des langues ... Heinrich Meidinger · 1836.

La couronne impériale n'étant plus respectée, tous ceux qui se croyaient lésés, cherchaient à se faire droit eux-mêmes. Le droit du plus fort ou droit manuaire (Faustrecht) domina exclusivement, trainant à sa suite cette série de violences et brigandages qui stygmatisent le treizième siècle.

Une définition plus instructive se trouve dans l'ouvrage suivant : CONSTITUTIONS DES PRINCIPAUX ÉTATS DE L' EUROPE ET DES ...
Jacques-Vincent Delacroix · 1791.
                    

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faustrecht: (lat. Jus manuarĭum), ancien droit germanique autorisant les hommes libres à réparer arme au poing (Faust) les atteintes à leur personne, leurs biens ou leur honneur sans faire d'abord appel à un juge.

@FrançoisJurain Exactement, j'avais commencé à rédiger une réponse quand ton commentaire a surgi - sans violence. À toi de rédiger la réponse. On trouve le mot dans les vieux dictionnaires bilingues (Allemand-Français), par exemple : https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Nouveau_dictionnaire_francois_allemand_e/uM5ZFDF3faEC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=manuaire&pg=PA582&printsec=frontcover

Juste +1 pour celle de LPH en ce qui me concerne. J'ajouterai juste un commentaire: droit du plus fort n'est pas synonyme de droit manuaire. C'est la traduction d'une acception différente de Faustrecht.

Un autre dictionnaire Français Allemand   un peu antérieur (1789 vs 1801) propose aussi "droit manuaire" comme traduction de "Kolbenrecht".

Sans aide contextuelle, je traduirais Kolbenrecht par droit des massues ce qui me paraît plus proche de droit du plus fort. Pt^t droit de duel judiciaire? Faustrecht est la modernisation de Fehderecht "droit de représailles". de Fehde "inimitié", cf. angl. feud, foe.
